# AngularJS - conditional ngStyle

Tags: angularjs, ng-style

Is there a possibility to do something like this:

```
<span data-ng-style="vm.myFlag == true ? 'background-color:{{myObject.color}};padding:2px;border-radius:2px;' : ''">
```

This if - else does not work. ngClass does not work because the color is a property of my object(s).

Comment: Try this `<span data-ng-style="vm.myFlag && {'background-color':myObject.color}">`

Comment: Try: <span data-ng-style="{'background-color: {{myObject.color}};padding:2px;border-radius:2px;' : vm.myFlag}>

Comment: Don't know if the {{myObject.color}} will work though; need to test.

Answer (score 2):

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle

Basic Example of ng-style :

```
<span ng-style="{'background-color':'blue'}">Sample Text</span>
```

Using ternary operator to make styling conditional on `vm.myFlag`:

```
<span data-ng-style="(vm.myFlag == true) ? {'background-color':
 myObject.color, 'padding': '2px', 'border-radius': '2px'}
 : {}">
```

Comment: Would you like to improve your code-only answer by augmenting it with some explanation?

Answer (score 0):

```
<span data-ng-style="vm.myFlag && {'background-color':myObject.color}">
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
<span data-ng-style="vm.geMyStyle()">
```

and in your controller:

```
vm.getMyStyle= func(){

    let style = vm.myFlag == true ? 'background-color:' 
    +myObject.color+';padding:2px;border-radius:2px;' : '';

    return style;
}
```

but you also should check if there is the color-property set.