# Conditional ng-style

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to change the border upon condition. I don't have any errors but it doesn't work.

```
<span   ng-style="{{thumb.Selected}} ? {'border' : 'red'}:{'border' : 'black'}" style="display:block; border:solid 1px black;"  >
```

Comment: does this answer your question?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45809564/angularjs-conditional-ngstyle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to put the condition in the curly braces. And as for ng-style here, the way I understand it is you are replacing the border property of the styles that are being applied to this element.

Also if you are trying to change the border I don't think border: red or border:black are valid css statements. One way to solve this problem is writing it like this

```
<span ng-style="thumb.selected ? {'border-color': 'red'} : {}" 
style="border:1px solid black">Your text here </span>
```

You might wanna look into [ng-style](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle) and [css border property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border.asp)